# In my theme folder ‘sfwd-lms/includes/shortcodes/ld_course_list.php’ file overwrite not working

Tags: wordpress, templates, plugins, overriding, learndash

I'm trying to overwrite my ld_course_list.php file, but I'm having trouble. I tried to use the same plugin folder structure in my child theme, but it did not display the child theme file content.

Plugin Name: LearnDash LMS

Plugin file location : wp-content/plugins/sfwd-lms/includes/shortcodes/ld_course_list.php

Child theme file location : wp-content/themes/Awake/sfwd-lms/ld_course_list.php

The other two locations were also tried:
(1) wp-content/themes/Awake/sfwd-lms/includes/ld_course_list.php
(2) wp-content/themes/Awake/sfwd-lms/includes/shortcodes/ld_course_list.php

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Overwriting `LearnDash` plugin files is not as straight forward as woocommerce, they follow a very different folder structure, try this path:

`wp-content/themes/Awake/learndash/shortcodes/ld_course_list.php`

or

`wp-content/themes/Awake/learndash/ld_course_list.php`

Unfortunately there is no proper official documentation on this. Check these articles for more info [Article 1](https://wisdmlabs.com/docs/article/wisdm-elumine-theme/for-developers/overriding-learndash-templates/) | [Article 2](https://diviengine.com/how-to-customize-a-learndash-template-in-your-child-theme/)

Comment: Unfortunately, your solution does not work for me.